# what are the suitable verbs for telling the presence of an object in image

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a journal paper and I am somehow confused how to find the best verb for these kind of sentences:

> 1) "In these images more than 5 objects are existed/appeared/presented ....."
>
> 2) "In that side of the street, No obstacles are existed/appeared/ ....."

Comment: "Are existed" and "are appeared" are not really an option. I'll be migrating this to our sister site for English Language Learners. Thank you.

Comment: *Appear* and *exist* are intransitive, so they can't appear in the passive.

Answer (score 1):

We would need to know more about the context to say for sure, but here are my suggestions:

> 1) In these images, more than five objects can be seen...
>
> 2) **On** that side of the street, no obstacles are found...

I assume you want verbs that not only talk about the obstacles in the images, but also how the reader can see those obstacles in the image.

Notice also that the preposition *on* is predominate when talking about the two sides of the street.